# How to interpret numbers with leading zero's as decimal?

Tags: decimal, python-2.x, octal

all!
I need to interpret numbers given with leading zeros in python as decimal. ( on input there are numbers, not strings!)
Python2 is used, in python3 there are no more such problem.
I haven't ideas how to do this. 
Anybody help me please!!!

example:

```
id = 0101
print id
# will print 65 and I need 101

id = 65
print id
# will print 65 - ok
```

possible solution:

```
id = 0101

id = oct(id).lstrip('0')

print id
# will print 101 - ok

id = 65

id = oct(id).lstrip('0')

print id
# will print 101 - wrong, need 65
```

Comment: Why do you need this? A numeric literal starting with 0 should be octal.

Comment: for `65` which is printing `101` is wrong as per you, so what is the right answer. Can't figure out what do you need?

Comment: What should `print(oct(65))` produce?

Comment: Are the values literals in a script? Or is the user entering data e.g. using `raw_input`? Or is it being read from a file? I'm not sure I understand how you're ending up with the problem you say you have.

Answer (score 1):

It is a normal behaviour for Python2. This kind of numbers are [specified in the language](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals):

> `octinteger     ::=  "0" ("o" | "O") octdigit+ | "0" octdigit+`

`"0" octdigit+` - numbers that are started with `"0"` - are octal by design. You can't change this behaviour.

If you want to interpret `077` as `77`, the most you can do is some kind of ugly transformations like it:

`int(str(oct(077)).lstrip('0'))`

Comment: yes, but I need change this behaviour if it's possible, I need return the same digit that give me user

Comment: It is how Python2 works. It is impossible unless you will rewrite the part of Python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Can you cast it to string?

For example:

```
def func(rawNumber):

   id = str(rawNumber)
   if id[0] == '0':
      res = oct(id).lstrip('0')
   else:
      res = id
   return int(res)

# then use it like this:

print(func(0101)) # will print 101
print(func(65))  # will print 65
```

Comment: after casting to string id = 0101 we became string '65' - it's no solution,

Comment: try to test your example here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php both prints 65